# How can I get the value from array object?

Tags: angular, file, object

I am trying to download a file from the browser and I can see the file from the API response.

I am now stuck while trying to access the file by getting the value from the array object. I have tried to drill into the object, but am unable to get the filename so that I can download it.

How can I get the file name from the array object?

**JSON response**

```
{
 "version": "1.1",
 "content": {
"headers": [
  {
    "key": "Content-Type",
    "value": [
      "text/csv"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Content-Disposition",
    "value": [
      "attachment; filename=Customer_9695_20231013_0940.csv"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
    "value": [
      "Content-Disposition"
    ]
  }
]
},
"statusCode": 200,
"reasonPhrase": "OK",
"headers": [],
"trailingHeaders": [],
"requestMessage": null,
"isSuccessStatusCode": true
```

**My code**

```
downloadFile()
{
try
{
    var _pID = this.reseller.pID;
    var _customerID = this.reseller.customerID;
    
        //Now calling download service
        this.rateSheetService.downlaodCSV(_pID, _customerID).then((data) => {
               
                var responseData = data;
                console.log("responseData", responseData);

                const dataArray = data['content'];
                const headers = dataArray['headers'];
                const response = headers[1];
                const content = response['value'];
                const fileIndex = content[0];

                //I now want to get the file name inside "content"

                const linkSource = 'data:text/csv';
                const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
                const fileName = fileIndex['filename'];
                downloadLink.href = linkSource; 
                const csv = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/csv' });
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(csv);
                console.log("url", url);                    
        });
}
catch(e)
{
    console.log("Checking the errors ", e)
}
}
```

**Response**

[image: Response]